# Looping an Extraction Process over Objects

Tags: r

I'm a bit new with looping, and would like to write a code that automates extracting rows of many object in the R-workspace.

I have 15 R objects in the same directory that I load using this loop:

```
library(miceadds)
for(i in 1990:2004){
  fname = paste('C:/Users/Adrian/abc', i , 'test.RData' , sep="")
  load.Rdata(fname , paste("abc" , i , sep = ""))
}
```

The objects are loaded and named "abc" with a year (1990 to 2004). These objects are huge matrices with same dimensions, that contain both strings and numeric values. I would like to extract the same rows from each of these 15 objects in an elegant way.

Of course, I could always use something like: `abc1990[grep("Birds", abc1990$column1), ]` and repeat 15 times. Would there be a more efficient way?

Comment: Put the objects into a list when you load them. Then you can iterate over that list easily.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you give an example code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# this is all the file names
fname <- paste0('C:/Users/Adrian/abc', 1990:2004 , 'test.RData')

# load all files into a list
list_of_matrices <- lapply(fname, load.Rdata)

# a function to grep the rows that you want from ONE matrix
extractMyRows <- function(MATRIX) {MATRIX[grep("Birds", abc1990$column1), ]}

# and now apply this function to all elements of the list
lapply(list_of_matrices, extractMyRows)
```